# Why is the "+" operator not Sendable

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I have a snippet of code where I sum up the values of an `AsyncSequence` as seen below, but I get a warning on the plus operator: `Converting non-sendable function value to '@Sendable (Int, Int) async -> Int' may introduce data races`

```swift
let asyncSequence = // ...
let emittedSummationSequence = asyncSequence
.scan(0, +) // error here
// ...
```

Changing the offending line to

```
.scan(0, { $0 + $1 })
```

makes the problem go away, which seems to point to the culprit being that the `+` operator isn't marked `Sendable`. Any reason why this is so, and is there any non-intrusive fix to make the operator `Sendable`?

Comment: Not sure about the `.scan`, but what if you tried the `.reduce` instead?

Comment: Interesting find! It looks like the [Swift Evolution proposal for this feature](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0302-concurrent-value-and-concurrent-closures.md) makes no mention of operators. I guess the inference for explicit closures doesn't automatically apply to them.